# Run scripts in other instances and pass variables from the first script to the second

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I have the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $RenderClient -Recurse -Filter "ffmpeg crop.ps1" |
  Where-Object { Test-Path (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName *.mp4) } |
  ForEach-Object {
  try {
  Start-Process -WorkingDirectory $_.DirectoryName powershell.exe "-NoExit -File `"$($_.FullName)`""
  }
  catch {
  Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red "Não foi possivel cortar o arquivo:"; Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White " $_.Name "; Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White "`nMensagem de erro:"; Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red " $($_.Exception.Message)`n";
   }
  }
 }
```

This code is a part of my first script, basically it looks for `ffmpeg crop.ps1` files that have a `.mp4` file in the same folder and runs those scripts.

The issue is that I would like to make the process a little cleaner and more practical, currently when I need to make a change in the `ffmpeg crop` script I need to open all the folders and change one by one.

To avoid this, I would like to have a single file `ffmpeg crop.ps1`, and every time a `.mp4` file is found in the path specified in the first script, an instance of that single script `ffmpeg crop.ps1` is triggered, too I need `$_.FullName` and `$_.Name` of each `.mp4` file found to be passed to each respective instance so that I can use these values ​​within the `ffmpeg crop` script.

I've been racking my brain for days trying to get this to work, I'll be very grateful for any help with this.

### Edit - in more detail

The $RenderClient folder of my script is `C:/Videos` inside that folder there are several child folders that follow the logic: `01-01`, `01-02`,`02-01`, `02-02`...

[image]

Currently, inside each child folder there is a script `ffmpeg crop.ps1`, this script is responsible for cutting a piece of the video that is inside that folder, however it is only activated if there is a `.mp4` file to be cut, in the same folder that it, that is, for the script `ffmpeg crop.ps1` to be activated in folder `01-01`, it is necessary to have the script itself and a `.mp4` file.

**This script would be triggered**

[image]

**This script would not be triggered**

[image]

The point is, I would like to make this more practical, so instead of having one `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script inside each child folder, I would like to have only one `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script, and it would stay in the parent folder.

**I would like it to work like this:**

[image]

For that, I would need to change my code, so that the script recursively searches for `.mp4` files inside the parent folder, for each file that is found, it must open an instance of the script `ffmpeg crop.ps1` that is in the parent folder and pass the variables `$_.Name` and `$_.FullName` of the files found to the respective instance of the open `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script, so that each instance will be executed correctly.

Comment: That's very hard to understand, at least to me. So, to rephrase: you want to run the MP4 files found in the same directory as your PS1, as an argument to your PS1? Then do the same for the other directories that have that one PS1 found, and just run them all against that same one in that directory?

Comment: I edited my question and tried to make it more detailed, see if you understand. Any questions let me know

Comment: If that's the case, why not leave the PS1 in the top level directory, search for MP4 files, and just call on the script. Basically what you're already doing if you just place it in the parent folder: `gci $RenderClient *.MP4 -File -Recurse | % { start PowerShell "-File '$RenderClient\ffpmeg crop.ps1' $($_.FullName)"`

Comment: If that's the case, why not leave the PS1 in the top level directory, search for MP4 files, and just call on the script. Basically what you're already doing if you just place it in the parent folder: `gci $RenderClient *.MP4 -File -Recurse | % { start PowerShell "-File '$RenderClient\ffpmeg crop.ps1' $($_.FullName)"`

Comment: Right, but I still need to pass the `$_FullName` variables (path of each .mp4 found) to the respective open instance, because I need to use this path in the ffmpeg command that exists inside the `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script, as I can do that?

Comment: You mean like the above code, or: `gci $RenderClient *.MP4 -File -Recurse | % { start PowerShell "-File", "\`"$RenderClient\ffpmeg crop.ps1\`"", $_.DirectoryName, $_.Name`? Still the same logic as previously mentioned, just not sure what you mean by variables since you mentioned the FullName property and name of the object in your post.

Comment: What parameters does your PS1 need/take? The path to the file? The file path? The directory path and file name?

Comment: Inside the `ffmpeg crop.ps1` file I need to have the path of the `.mp4` file and its name.

Currently, as there is an `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script in each folder and the video file is in the same folder as it, I simply use `./file.mp4`, now I will need the file path and name to be passed to each respective instance.

Comment: Perhaps you are not understanding what I am trying to do. Notice, the script I posted is the one I currently have, but it needs to be modified. See that first it looks for files with the name `ffmpeg crop.ps1`, then in each folder it finds these files, it checks if there is a `.mp4` file together, if it exists it runs this script and the script in turn does the work to cut the video. The issue is that as I have a file in each folder, I don't need to pass any value to it, the path of the `.mp4` file is the script's folder itself. Right?

Comment: Now, as I want to have only one ffmpeg crop.ps1 file, and this file will be in the parent folder, I need to change the logic of my script, instead of looking for `ffmpeg crop.ps1` files, it needs to look for files `.mp4`. Then, for each `.mp4` found, it needs to run an instance of `ffmpeg crop.ps1` that is in the parent folder and pass it the path and name of that file in a variable, note that each file found is in a different folder . I tried passing the file path with `-ArgumentList` and getting it into the `ffmpeg crop.ps1` file using `args[0]` and `args[1]`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: So, 2 it takes 2 arguments? If you run your PS1 directly from the command line, how would you pass it values? `.\script.ps1 "directory" "filename.mp4"`, or just `.\script.ps1 "directory\filename.mp4"`?

Comment: That's right, I need to pass 2 arguments, one is the full file path and the other is just the file name. If I can pass the full path, it would be great, because from it I can get the file name

Comment: If you place your PS1 in the root folder (*which is `$RenderClient`* - `C:\Videos`), my 2nd suggestion should work. Have you tried it? If you want the `FullName` property(*which includes the filename*), use: `gci $RenderClient *.MP4 -File -Recurse | % { start PowerShell "-File", "\`"$RenderClient\ffpmeg crop.ps1\`"", $_.FullName`. Now, the script is located in one place and a new instance is created per .MP4 file found passing it the entire path as the argument.

Comment: Not yet, I'll try it now, but how do I access the value of $_.FullName in the ffmpeg crop.ps1 script?

Comment: What do you mean? If it accepts a parameter argument, the last suggestion should work by passing it the `FullName` property to the script; a.k.a., the PowerShell instance running the script. `Start-Process` will open a PowerShell instance per file passing it the files location via `$_.FullName`.

Comment: The issue is that inside the `ffmpeg crop` script I have a `$FilePath` variable that currently has the value of `.\*.mp4`, now I need its value to be received from the first script, which calls the `ffmpeg crop` script, this is the point. I need `$FilePath` to be received from the first script.

Comment: So you want the directory path (`C:\Videos\folder\ `) where the file is, and not the full path (`C:\Videos\folder\file.mp4`)? Then change it to `$_.DirectoryName` instead of `$_.FullName`.

Comment: I tried your code, but I had to make some modifications for it run, it looked like this: `gci $RenderClient *.MP4 -File -Recurse | % { start PowerShell "-File", "`"$RenderClient\ffmpeg crop.ps1`"", $_.FullName}`

Powershell instances flash quickly and close.

Comment: I changed my `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script, I left it like this so I can visualize what happens:
`$FilePath= $_.FullName

Write-Host "$FilePath"

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"`

Comment: The idea is that in each instance that opens I can see a different `$FilePath`, but the instances are opening and closing quickly.

Comment: Is there an error? Use `gci $RenderClient *.MP4 -File -Recurse | % { start PowerShell "-NoExit", "-File", "\`"$RenderClient\ffpmeg crop.ps1\`"", $_.DirectoryName }`

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that the script name was wrong, it was `ffpmeg crop.ps1` instead of `ffmpeg crop.ps1`, I adjusted it and the instances remained open, but I get this error here: `It's not possible
process the argument because the value of the "name" argument is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the
operation again.`

Comment: That's an error with the script you're calling. You need to see why it's not accepting it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251605/discussion-between-tyrone-hirt-and-abraham-zinala).

Comment: The script I'm calling has this exact code here:
`$FilePath= $_.FullName

Write-Host "$FilePath"

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"`

I just left this in the script that is called to be able to visualize what happens

Comment: I tested leaving the `ffmpeg crop.ps1` script completely blank, to see if I still get the same error, and the error keeps popping up, which indicates that the error is in the code that calls the script. if I remove `$._FullName` from the calling script I don't get any error messages. I have no more ideas...